# apache - python How to delete a file using a command or a python script?

Tags: python, apache, webserver, simulation, delete-file

I am using apache and I will try to make a small script to simulate the device and I need it to delete lines or even the whole txt file. But I can't find it online, so I am asking. Somebody with solutions?

I have txt files created and logs written in them after the intervals I have given, I just don't know how to incorporate deletion. Do you know of a Python command for apache so I can delete a line or a whole txt file?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fileinput` module. Try below code to delete the lines in a txt file -

```
import fileinput
import os

def delete_line(file_path, line_number, operation=None):

    if operation == 'delete_file':
        os.remove(file_path)

    with fileinput.FileInput(file_path, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as f:
        for index, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            if index != line_number:
                print(line, end='')


delete_line("YourTextFile.txt", 4, operation='delete_file')
```

You can also refer to this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html).